# Caching Three.js pages offline on mobile in Reading List

Tags: android, ios, mobile, three.js, webgl

I created some simple Three.js model viewers and apps for our sales team to show at events. Often there is no wifi or internet and they are using iPads or iPhones to show these web pages.

At first, we saved the pages in the Reading List on Chrome mobile (Safari seemed to bodge up and break the WebGL content when saving it). This cached reading list page works fine for a day or so (tested with wifi and data off and no live pages open), but a few days later, the reading list pages do not load as if the cached data they had saved was expired?

**This is very simple to recreate:**

1. Save page to Reading List
2. Disable data and wifi, close all pages
3. Open Reading List page, works fine, try several times to be sure
4. Close all apps, switch off the phone, leave it off for a few days
5. Switch on phone, disable data/wifi
6. Open Chrome, open Reading List page, doesn't load any more

Comment: This question might not be related to Three.js. If I understand correctly, do you intend to have something similar to offline functionality of PWA? If so, you could use service workers but that's a broad topic. This page should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers

Comment: I initially assumed it was more three.js specific as when the pages are saved offline, a few days later the actual webpage itself shows fine but the three.js viewer window either doesn't load or only some parts of it load. We are trying to disable the expiry of the cookies on the webpages next week to test and see if it is a cookie expiry causing it.